# How to evaluate $\int \sqrt{x^3+x^4} dx$

Tags: calculus

Find the integral: $\int \sqrt{x^3+x^4} dx$

I know I could use WolframAlpha, but I wonder if there is a way to calculate this integral in a nice way (some clever substitution perhaps?).

Tried a lot of different ways, but don't seem to find a good way.

I don't want you to calculate the whole integral, I just ask you for a little hint.

Comment: The solution is not very pretty

Comment: I know. I just hoped to find one a little prettier than the Wolfram's.

Comment: @user142866 Hope is a good thing. Maybe, the best of things.

Comment: A pity: if it were $\;x^2\;$ instead of that nasty $\;x^3\;$ then there is a slick solution...

Comment: @DonAntonio: This problem is tagged as "hard" in my coursebook. But you're right, if it were $x^2$ I wouldn't need to seek for some help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggested method, which involves completing the square and then two substitutions.

$$\sqrt{x^3+x^4}=\frac x2\sqrt{(2x+1)^2-1}$$

Now set $y=2x+1, dy=2dx, x=\frac {y-1}2$ and the integrand becomes $$\frac {y-1}8\cdot\sqrt {y^2-1}$$

Then use the substitution $y=\cosh z$